# Make Text Box visible with condition

Tags: vba, textbox, conditional-statements, visible

I am new at VBA and I am trying some code and I could not find a solution or where I am doing wrong.

What I want: The combination of two different text boxes make another text box visible(so it starts in useform not visible). With one condition I could do it using select case(LLL) but when I try it with another variant it does not work(XXX). There is no error message, the code runs but does not show the text box.

```
Sub Visible() 

If userform.TextBox5.Value = "XXX" And userform.TextBox10.Value = "245" Then
    userform.TextBox1.Visible = True
    userform.T_1.Visible = True
  Else
    GoTo LLL
End If

LLL:
Select Case True
           
    Case userform.TextBox5.Value = "LLL", userform.TextBox10.Value >= "145"
        If userform.Option000.Value = True Then
         userform.TextBox1.Visible = True
         userform.T_1.Visible = True
        Else
         userform.TextBox1.Visible = False
         userform.T_1.Visible = False
End If

    
End Select
```

I understand some of your questions I must say that my code is quite big one cause it is linked to SAP in order to get some values from there and due to its size the complete code is splitted in modules and I am only sharing the module where I am facing problems.

There is one case for select case statement cause it was the only way that it worked close for what I need. I have a lot of variables for the fields TextBox5 and TextBox10 the values of these textboxes come from SAP and when I combine them, other Text Boxes shall be visible depending on the variables given. The problem is that for just one combination (this one is the one that I applied the select case statement) I need another variable (option000) so that TextBox1 and T_1 become visible. When I tried to do it only with if statements it did not worked.

Comment: You can add `Debug.Print` or `MsgBox` in strategic places to see where it is going wrong. Like, after an `If` to see if it resolves as intended.

Comment: Many potential issues here. You have a Goto LLL but there is nothing stopping the code from going there without the goto. You probably meant to put an Exit Sub before LLL: to prevent the code from just continuing into LLL unless told to goto. Other than that, you have a comparison >= "145" which may fail because it could be comparing string values. For example "aaa" >= "145" is True. I'm also not understanding the purpose of the select case since there is only one case.